# .htaccess redirection to avoid 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently make changes in my CMS, which cause lots of 404 error in google webmaster. Currently 404 not found URL are

http://pukhtoogle.com/gallery/postcard.img707.htm

Whereas the working URL is

http://pukhtoogle.com/gallery/img707.htm

I want to exclude postcard from the URL via .htaccess, please suggest a line to replace it, following code shows my existing file.

```
RewriteEngine On 

#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ google.php
RewriteRule ^cat-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.htm$ categories.php?cat_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^cat\.htm$ categories.php?%{QUERY_STRING}

#Mod_bmollet : Image name in URL
RewriteRule ^img-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.htm$ details.php?image_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^img([0-9]+)\.search.htm$ details.php?image_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^img([0-9]+)\.lightbox.htm$ details.php?image_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^img([0-9]+)\.htm$ details.php?image_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^img([0-9]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.htm$ details.php?image_id=$1&mode=$2&%        {QUERY_STRING}


#Mod_bmollet : This is to make search function work ( redirect links from search results )
RewriteRule ^search\.htm$ search.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^search\.([0-9]+)\.htm$ search.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^lightbox\.htm$ lightbox.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^lightbox\.([0-9]+)\.htm$ lightbox.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right under the `RewriteEngine On` in your htaccess file, add:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/postcard\.(.*)$ /gallery/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

EDIT: After playing around on your website for a little while, it would appear all these rules are *actually in the `gallery` directory*, which would have been invaluable information to know from the start.

Because of this, you must omit the `gallery/` part of the regular expression:

```
RewriteRule ^postcard\.(.*)$ /gallery/$1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^postcard\.(.*)$ http://pukhtoogle.com/gallery/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I have placed the line, but still same result you can check the URL.

Comment: @MoxetKhan and all your other rules work? Is your htaccess file in your document root?

Comment: Yes, all other rules works. I have 1 ht file on root pukhtoogle.com for joomla, and 2nd on /gallery for 4images. other rules working accurate as 4images is PHP cms and the URL is converted into HTML so far with htaccess.

Comment: @MoxetKhan Yeah, it's pretty important to know where the htaccess file is before composing rules, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Cheer! Working 100% now, thank you very much dear..